# Help me find a name for this method

Tags: c#, .net

I want to give a meaningfull name for method which i am not able to find enough good. Method should to lock and unlock user by parameter .

Candidates signs are:

```
void LockUser(int userid,bool @lock)
void LockUser(int userid,bool @locking)
void LockOrUnlockUser(int userid,bool @lock)

void LockUser(int userid);
void UnlockUser(int userid);
```

problem at first and second is method name says lockuser but it is also able to unlock user by lock parameter so this is confusing. LockOrUnlock method name is more meaningfull but i couldn't find better parameter name for it. It can be shouldLock ? 
Another apporach is seperate them to different methods and this provide more meaningfull names for methods but i want to just use one method instead of both.

Waiting suggestions.

Comment: LockUser / UnclockUser its obvious by name what it does, you dont have to check parameters etc

Comment: This should probably be posted on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Be original, call it foo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Martin Fowler** [suggests](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html) using separate methods. Otherwise you implement a **Flag Argument** method, which he believes to be a **bad design choice**.

> A flag argument is a kind of function argument that tells the function
>   to carry out a different operation depending on its value.
>
> My general reaction to flag arguments is to avoid them. Rather than
>   use a flag argument, I prefer to define separate methods.

Comment: In my example, i can not really call it as a flag parameter because method parameter does not cause any conditional check inside. It is kind of setter method. I agree what you have said for flag operators but this is not that case.

Comment: In that case go for sth like `SetLockState(int userId, LockState state)`

Answer (score 2):

Replace `bool @lock` with an `enum` - that's arguably better design-wise. As for naming, maybe `ToggleUserLock(int userID, UserLock @lock)`?

Answer (score 1):

"SetUserLock(int userid, bool @lock)"

"ToggleUserLock(int userid)"

Answer (score 0):

How about SetUserLockStatus()

as technically you are setting the Lock/Unlock status from parameters

Answer (score 0):

How about

> ChangeUserLockStatus